# HTML5 video embed with Flowplayer doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, html, video, mp4, flowplayer

I try to add a video. It doesn't work inside the client's environment, so I created a sandbox with minimal code: http://sandbox.knsqnt.com/

The problem is, that it works fine except on iPad / iPhone. The given error is "html5: Video file not found".

The MIME types are set correctly and even my webhoster couldn't find any wrong configurations.

There are a lot of topics to this issue, but I couldn't find one helping me with my problem. Can you help me? Tanks.

Comment: Have you tried playing the video directly in the iPad/iPhone browser?

Comment: Thanks for this hint. The codec was the problem... Thanks.